# Linked lists in MIPS - point of example?

Tags: linked-list, mips

I am working with linked lists in MIPS, and have one example that I am not sure about. It says:
write function rotate(head, a, b) that rotates elements of linked lists from position a to position b, such that if element was on position i(that belongs segment a,b) its new position is b+a-i. Numbers a,b are choosen such that a<b. Now, I don't get point of this example, because after we change elements for every position i, list will stay the same because of the formula(also it is considered that position of elements in list starts with 1 and goes to length of list).

Also, for every node in list, I think it is enough to replace only value field for corresponding indexes right(next field is not neccessary). Last sentence I am considering only if I had example where elements of list would really change(if my assumption above is correct).

Comment: There's not really any MIPS in this question yet. It's just trying to understand the assignment. Write out an example, say, starting with [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], and the perform a rotate(head, 3, 5), then the result is [ 1, 2, **5, 4, 3**, 6, 7].

Comment: But if you use i=3, than we need to swap elements on position 3 and 3+5-3(5),  and after that we get list that you got. Then for i=4, nothing happens. But for i=5, we need to swap element on position 5 with element on position 3+5-5(3), and that gives us list  from the begging, right? I mean, there is nowhere said we need to stop at i=5, it says for every i in [3,5].

Comment: The instructions didn't say "Perform this sequence of swaps." It says "The element at position i moves to position b+a-i." So the element originally at position i=3 ends at position 5+3-3=5; the element originally at position i=4 ends at to position 5+3-4=4; the element originally at position 5 ends at position 5+3-5=3.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, my bad. And for my second question, is it enough to modify only value field for every node?

Comment: Typically, these types of exercises want to reorder the nodes, not copy the values. In the more general case, the values aren't just integers; they're more complicated things that might not be copyable. But really this is something you should clarify with your instructor. (Also, confirm with your instructor that getting assistance from the Internet is allowed.)

Comment: Yes, it is allowed, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Some schools consider it a violation of academic honesty get outside assistance on assignments. Others permit it, but require you to cite the assistance you received (to avoid plagiarism).

Comment: Write it in C and then translate to MIPS.  I know you don't need it in C but it is so much easier to write MIPS when you know what you're trying to do.